# Why is it possible to replace 都 with 也 in 什么都没有?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I know 也 only as "also", but I see it now and then used in ways difficult to understand, especially in some negative statements. Why is this so? Does 也 also have some meaning not mentioned in dictionaries which is used in these cases?

Comment: In this case, 也 equals to either/neither in English. That is, 也 can be used as also, too, either, neither. Sounds confusing. :P

Comment: @Flake: It is! I wonder why is this not in any dictionary I have!

Comment: Actually, as I can recall, there is no difference between "too" and "either" or "neither" in Chinese at all. E.g. 我也有iPhone <-> 我也没有iPhone. This may be the reason it is not even mentioned -- because there is no difference in Chinese as it is in English between positive and negative forms.

Comment: @Flake This should be a good answer. :)

Comment: @Flake: Are you saying that "我也有iPhone" and "我也没有iPhone" mean the same thing?

Comment: @drHannibalLecter No. These two phrases are examples to demonstrate that `也` equals to both `also/too` and `either` in English. ;) Hope this helps.

Comment: @Flake: I think I got it: "I don't have iPhone either". When you use your second language to learn your third language sometimes you have a brain fart :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

什麼都 can be used in both positive and negative statements while 什麼也 is usually used in negative statements. So, instead of focusing on the usage of 也 here, 什麼都 and 什麼也 can be regarded as phrases which are sometimes used interchangeably.

For example:

> 我們以為什麼都知道，而實際上什麼也不知道。/ 我们以为什么都知道，而实际上什么也不知道。

One possible translation:

> We thought we knew/know everything but, in fact, we knew/know nothing at all.

So, it's ok to say (although the above example would read better):

> 我們以為什麼都知道，而實際上**什麼都**不知道。/ 我们以为什么都知道，而实际上**什么都**不知道。

but odd to say:

> 我們以為**什麼也**知道，而實際上什麼也不知道。/ 我们以为**什么也**知道，而实际上什么也不知道。

Comment: good answer.but i never thought about it althrough i say it everyday.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of the original expression is "I have nothing." But Chinese gets there in a "strange," way.

A more literal translation of the expression is "Everything not have." The "everything" is rendered by "什麼都," which literally translates to "whatever all."

什麼也 gets to the same place in a slightly different way. I would translate it as "whatever included." And a literal translation would be "whatever included, not have," instead of "whatever all" not have.